# C++ Memory Error on Delete - Debug Assertion Failed

Tags: c++, memory, vector

I am trying to add a set of new ModelImages to a vector, and am getting an error, Debug Assertion Failed, Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse). This occurs when trying to delete the second ModelImage that is generated.

```
std::vector<ModelImage> ModelImages;

for(int n=0;n<nParamSets;n++)
{
    ModelImage* mI = new ModelImage(MOD_WIDTH,MOD_HEIGHT);
    ModelImages.push_back(*mI);
    delete mI;
}
```

The constructor and destructor, and copy and swap funcitons, are as follows:

```
ModelImage(int _width, int _height)
{
    width = _width;
    height = _height;
    nPixels = width*height;
    distance =  new float[nPixels];
    intensity = new float[nPixels];
    derivX =    new float[nPixels];
    derivY =    new float[nPixels];
    maxDistance = 0.0f;
    minDistance = 0.0f;
}

~ModelImage()
{
    delete [] derivX;
    delete [] derivY;
    delete [] distance;
    delete [] intensity;
}

ModelImage& operator=(ModelImage other)
{
    swap(*this, other);
    return *this;
} 

friend void swap(ModelImage& first, ModelImage& second)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(first.derivX,second.derivX);
    swap(first.derivY,second.derivY);
    swap(first.distance,second.distance);
    swap(first.intensity,second.intensity);

    swap(first.nPixels,second.nPixels);
    swap(first.width,second.width);
    swap(first.height,second.height);
}
```

Just before trying to delete the second ModelImage, looking at the vector ModelImages shows that the two ModelImages in the vector have the same assigned memory addresses for the distance, intensity, derivX, derivY arrays.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I do have a copy constructor, and have just included that here.

Comment: I don't see a copy constructor in your update.  It would have a signature that looks something like `ModelImage(ModelImage const& other);`

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out explicitly - I hadn't realised I hadn't implemented the copy part of the copy and swap idiom, and thought that I had. My first time working with them.

Comment: Why are you not doing `ModelImages.push_back(ModelImage(MOD_WIDTH,MOD_HEIGHT));`? The dynamic allocation inside the loop is unnecessary and just odd if you're going to store the image by value in the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess is that you don't have a copy constructor defined. The vectors' `push_back` will default copy construct your `ModelImage` which will simply copy the member pointers but not reallocate the memory they point to.
However, these references will be gone after the original objects are deleted.

Hint: A copy constructor is something like:

```
ModelImage(const ModelImage& orig) {
  // appropriately reinitialize from orig
}
```

Not to confuse with the assignment `operator==`

Why do you do create these `ModelImage`s dynamically anyway (if you throw them right away)?
And why don't you take `vector<float>(nPixels)` instead of `new float[nPixels]`?

Comment: Creating them dynamically because I tried ModelImage mI(MOD_WIDTH,MOD_HEIGHT);    ModelImages.push_back(*mI); And that also didn't work.

Comment: have you tried `ModelImages.push_back( ModelImage(MOD_WIDTH, MOD_HEIGHT) );` ? But that won't fix your issue with the copy constructor either ...

Answer (score 3):

This is likely due to you not having a copy constructor.

Create a copy constructor that makes copies of the memory that your pointers are referencing.

When using std containers, they usually will create copies of your object as you insert.  As you have no copy constructor, all your member pointers end up pointing to the same memory address because it's simply doing a member-wise copy of your data.  Once one of the temporary copies is destructed, (or when you call delete on the original object after the insert) the memory of the object inserted has had it's memory deleted from under it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from what you've posted whether or not you have a proper copy constructor and assignment operator for the following members:

```
distance
intensity
derivX
derivY
```

If not, you need those. (see [Rule of three (C++ programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) for a bit more information).

A better alternative would be to use `std::vector<double>` for those data members.  That way copying, assignment, and destruction would all be handled automatically.  You'd still want to construct them to have the proper number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have all of the arrays defined as pointers in the class.  The default copy copies the values of the pointer meaning that when you delete the pointer in the outer function you delete the underlining memory.

Just a couple of suggestions

-Utilize Vector instead of a float * std::vector has copy and    move constructors defined allread

-The loop doesn't need to use the free store at all value semantics and coping are fully supported and less error prone.

```
 for(int n=0;n<nParamSets;n++)
 {       
     ModelImages.push_back( ModelImage(MOD_WIDTH,MOD_HEIGHT));
 }
```